# Routing and URI parsing in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-url

I have a route defined in CI,

`$route['user/activate-account/:any'] = "user/activate_account";`

People access the route in this url pattern,

`http://mydomain.com/user/activate-account/user_id/12345/token/abcdefghijk`

Inside the `activate_account` function, I tried to use the following codes to retrieve the required data,

```
$user_id=$this->input->get('user_id');
$token=$this->input->get('token');
```

But they return FALSE, does this mean that for this kind of url pattern, I am supposed to use the functions provided by the URI class (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html) to retrieve the variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your url is re-routed, you would need to use:

```
$usre_id = $this->uri->rsegment(n);
```

[Check out docs for more info.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html)

Comment: After changing the route to $route['user/activate-account/(:any)'] = "user/activate_account/$1"; I can use $this->uri->rsegment(4) and $this->uri->rsegment(6) to retrieve my needed data. Thanks for your help.